# CSS floated div overlapping or not moving downward when resize the window

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need 2 div with one is floated left so when we resize the window into a small window the second div will move downward.

```css
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="float: left">
            aaa
        </div>
        <div>
            bbb
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

this code will make the second div overlap with the first div, if I add display:flex in the container it won't overlap anymore but the div size is resizing with the windows size and the second div won't go downward.

What is wrong? I need my div to be exactly 500px.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to make the second div go down after resizing the browser. So you can use media queries for that:

```
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container div:first-child {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container div:last-child {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .container div:last-child {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      aaa
    </div>
    <div>
      bbb
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I separated the style of the two divs, and removed the `float:left` from the inline style. The `<meta>` is also important for the media query to work. I used `clear:both` to clear the float of the first div from the second, thus not affecting the second div.

I didn't put this in a snippet because the media does not seem to work there, but is working in my computer

Comment: Correction. The div will go down correctly but still overlapping if the window size is above 500px.

Comment: You can adjust the max-width to the width that you want. I thought the default behaviour is the overlap one

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `float` in second div also. Or in media query you have to set the `display: block` in both div. check updated snippet below..

```css
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="float: left">
            aaa
        </div>
        <div style="float: right">
            bbb
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: float right make the second div go to the rightside of the window, what I want is like when i put the display : flex in the class container, but adding display : flex doesn't make it go down when I resize the window. By the way I have tried to add both div display : block but it's not working as well :)